# How to view changes on branch that are not on master yet?

Tags: git, branch, diff

*UPD*

1. create repository (ForkPoint)
2. create branch
3. do some commit to branch
4. switch back to `master`
5. do same of some changes on the `master`, as on the branch
   (for example on branch you add line 'a' and remove 'b', and edit 'c'.
   on `master` do same: add line 'a', remove 'b' but edit 'd')
6. do some commit on `master`

So, now, on `master`, we have:

```
$ git diff ForkPoint..master:HEAD
@@@patch@@@  
new line 'a'  
removed line 'b'  
edited line 'd'
```

On branch, we have:

```
$ git diff ForkPoint..branch:HEAD
@@@patch@@@
new line 'a'
removed line 'b'
edited line 'c'
```

Now I want to see all changes on branch except those that are in `master` already.

```
$ git checkout master; git diff branch:HEAD
@@@patch@@@
edited line 'd'
edited line 'c'
```

*However*, I do not want to see other changes on `master` from `ForkPoint..master:HEAD`

**EXPECTED**

```
@@@patch@@@
edited line 'c'
```

I need something like

```
git cherry -v branch:HEAD
```

but this check whole commits. I need lines.

Comment: What is "HEAD" supposed to be in your example? It can't be the symbolic reference of the same name... Is it a path? Please clarify. I think your question would benefit from an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then Stack-Overflow users would know exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Git may not provide you with an option to accomplish this, but you may accomplish this with:

```
git diff master..mybranch | grep -v "^-[^-]"
```

this will remove all lines starting with a single "-", that is, any line that exist i `master` but not in `mybranch`.

You may need to adopt this depending on your environment.